# Error Analysis: count of errors

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a dataset look like this

```
Item    Correctness    Target    Answer
1.      Correct        1         1
2.      Correct        2         2
3.      Incorrect      3         4
4.      Incorrect      3         5
5.      Incorrect      3         6
6.      Correct        3         3 
7.      Correct        4         4
8.      Correct        5         5
9.      Incorrect      6         8
10.     Incorrect      6         8
11.     Incorrect      6         8
12.     Correct        6         6
13.     Correct        7         7
14.     Correct        8         8
15.     Correct        9         9
```

In order to do error analysis, I want to treat all the incorrect responses on the same target as one error. For example, there are four responses on target 3 (three incorrect ones and one correct response), so what I want to do is to say this subject made an error on target 3, and I don't care how many times he/she have tried to get the right response.

So should I create a new column to do that, or is there a function in R can help me calculate this? A sample code will be really helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Can you add expected output for your example data?

Comment: Maybe `unique(df1[ df1$Correctness == "Incorrect", "Target"])`, this will give you 3 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a data frame `df`, you can use `sqldf` package to do this likes the following sql format query:

```
 library(sqldf)
 result <- sqldf("SELECT Correctness, Target FROM df GROUP BY Correctness, Target")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using base R

Convert your Correctness column to `True`/`False`, then use the `any` function and `aggregate` on Target.

```
myDF$incorrect <- ifelse(myDF$Correctness == "Incorrect", T, F)
aggregate(myDF["incorrect"], by = myDF["Target"], FUN = any)
```

### Using data.table

You will need to load the data.table library first with `library(data.table)`. Once you do that this is more or less the same idea, but more succinct with better performance.

```
myDT[,incorrect:=ifelse(Correctness == "Incorrect", T, F),]
myDT[,any(incorrect),by=Target]
```

or simply

```
myDT[,any(ifelse(Correctness == "Incorrect", T, F)),by=Target]
```